\TblrNote don't show up in tabularray-table
It's as simple as that: my \TblrNotes in an tblr-environment don't appear in the pdf, luaTeX doesn't even complain, which it did when the document was longer (warning  (pdf backend): unreferenced destination with name 'tblr/1/a', which is note{a}). Some months ago, it did work, but by now it fails.
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,ngerman,DIV=16]{scrartcl}
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath} % I tried everything...
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\SetTblrStyle{note}{ hang = 2em, } % why not...
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{microtype}
\makeatletter
\DefTblrTemplate{note-tag}{default}{\textsuperscript{\InsertTblrNoteTag}} % in case it helps
\DefTblrTemplate{note-sep}{default}{\space}
\DefTblrTemplate{note-text}{default}{\InsertTblrNoteText}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \begin{tblr}[caption = none,%
    label = none,%
    note{a} = {Lauter a-Noten},%
    note{b}={Mit b-Note.},%
    note{c}={Tafellappen.},%
    note{d}={Geometrisches Mittel: \[\sqrt[11]{\prod^{11}_{i=1}x_i$}\]},
    ]%
    {colspec = {Q[1,si={table-format=4},c]Q[3,si={table-format=3.1},c]%
                Q[3,si={table-format=2.1},c]Q[3,si={table-format=2.1},c]Q[c]},
    }
    2005 & 301\TblrNote{a} & & & & \\
    2006 & 302 & 0,6 & -0,7 & ab\TblrNote{b} \\
    2007 & 303 & 0,4 & -0,6 &  bc\\
    2008 & 304 & 0,8 & -0,5 & cd\TblrNote{a} \\
    2009 & 305 & 0,6\TblrNote{c} & 0,3 & de \\
    2010 & 306 & 1,2 & -0,4 & ef \\
    2011 & 307 & 1,0 & -0,3 & fg \\
    2012 & 308 & 2,0 & -0,2\TblrNote{d} & gh \\
    2013 & 309 & 1,8 & -0,1 & hi \\
    2014 & 310 & 3,6 & 0,0 & ij \\
    2015 & 311 & 3,4 & 0,1 & jk \\
    2016 & 312 & 6,8 & 0,2 & kl \\
    2017 & 313 & 6,6 & 0,3 & lm \\
    2018 & 314 & 6,7 & 0,4 & mn \\
    2019 & 315 & 6,8 & 0,5 & no \\
    2020 & 316 & 7,0 & 0,6 & op \\
    2021 & 317 & 7,2 & 0,7\TblrNote{b} & pq \\
    2022 & 318 & 7,4 & 0,8\TblrNote{b} & qr \\
         & 319,1\TblrNote{a} & 1,3\TblrNote{a} & & \\\midrule
    \SetCell[c=2]{l} {{{2005--2022}}} & & 30,1 & 11,1 & ukw \\
         & & 36,2\TblrNote{a} & & \\\midrule
    2023 & 320 & 24 & 12,2 & swr\TblrNote{d} \\
    & & 8,0\TblrNote{a} & & kgb \\\midrule
  \end{tblr}
\end{document}


There are two issues.

tabularray only seems to allow notes in long tables. If you don't want to use the longtblr, you could probably use tblr with threeparttable or threeparttablex (untested).
You cannot use a display environment inside a note. So, any maths needs to be inline.


\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,ngerman,DIV=16]{scrartcl}
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DefTblrTemplate{note-sep}{default}{\space}
\DefTblrTemplate{note-text}{default}{\InsertTblrNoteText}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[caption = none,
  label = none,
  note{a} = {Lauter a-Noten},
  note{b}={Mit b-Note.},
  note{c}={Tafellappen.},
  note{d}={Geometrisches Mittel: $\sqrt[11]{\prod^{11}_{i=1}x_i}$},
  ]%
  {colspec = {Q[1,si={table-format=4},c]Q[3,si={table-format=3.1},c]%
      Q[3,si={table-format=2.1},c]Q[3,si={table-format=2.1},c]Q[c]},
  }
  \toprule
  2005 & 301\TblrNote{a} & & & & \\
  2006 & 302 & 0,6 & -0,7 & ab\TblrNote{b} \\
  2007 & 303 & 0,4 & -0,6 &  bc\\
  2008 & 304 & 0,8 & -0,5 & cd\TblrNote{a} \\
  2009 & 305 & 0,6\TblrNote{c} & 0,3 & de \\
  2010 & 306 & 1,2 & -0,4 & ef \\
  2011 & 307 & 1,0 & -0,3 & fg \\
  2012 & 308 & 2,0 & -0,2\TblrNote{d} & gh \\
  2013 & 309 & 1,8 & -0,1 & hi \\
  2014 & 310 & 3,6 & 0,0 & ij \\
  2015 & 311 & 3,4 & 0,1 & jk \\
  2016 & 312 & 6,8 & 0,2 & kl \\
  2017 & 313 & 6,6 & 0,3 & lm \\
  2018 & 314 & 6,7 & 0,4 & mn \\
  2019 & 315 & 6,8 & 0,5 & no \\
  2020 & 316 & 7,0 & 0,6 & op \\
  2021 & 317 & 7,2 & 0,7\TblrNote{b} & pq \\
  2022 & 318 & 7,4 & 0,8\TblrNote{b} & qr \\
  & 319,1\TblrNote{a} & 1,3\TblrNote{a} & & \\\midrule
  \SetCell[c=2]{l} {{{2005--2022}}} & & 30,1 & 11,1 & ukw \\
  & & 36,2\TblrNote{a} & & \\\midrule
  2023 & 320 & 24 & 12,2 & swr\TblrNote{d} \\
  & & 8,0\TblrNote{a} & & kgb \\\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}

A bug in Okular-on-X renders all my images worthless, so visual services are currently on hold. Thank you for your patience. [Right now, a kernel bug has prior call on my attention since that one causes the kernel to panic. Given that problem, Okular's peccadilloes are of negligible import. Without a kernel, I wouldn't have anything to take an image of. Not that I can actually do anything about either ....]
